# Requests doesn't work while Urllib2 does

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, urllib2, python-requests

I have a very simple example that I think `requests` should replace `urllib2` without problem. However, seems like in the simplest scenario, I am missing something. Can anyone tell me why? (I am trying to get the [makeup pricing](http://datafireball.com/2015/03/22/why-requests-is-not-working-well-as-well-as-urllib2/) for my GF　:) )

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
myurl = 'http://www.lancome-usa.com/skincare-cleanse/skincare-cleanse,default,sc.html'

# 1. urllib2
import urllib2
r = urllib2.urlopen(myurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
print 'MOUSSE RADIANCE' in soup.text.encode('utf-8').upper()
print '$32.00' in soup.text.encode('utf-8')

print '------------------------------------------------------'

# 2. requests
import requests
r = requests.get(myurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
print 'MOUSSE RADIANCE' in soup.text.encode('utf-8').upper()
print '$32.00' in soup.text.encode('utf-8')
```

Response:

```
True
True
------------------------------------------------------
False
False
```

---

In the end, I upgraded my `requests` library, also, I realized that using `r.text` won't work. But using `r.text.encode('utf-8')` and `r.content` will build the soup with the right content.

Comment: Does it work when you are using `r.raw` instead of `r.text`?

Comment: works for me, what version of requests are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upgrade your requests version, you can also get all the products in the `"product-name"` tag:

```
import requests
r = requests.get(myurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
products = {x.text.strip().lower() for x in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"product-name"})}

print("mousse radiance" in products)

for p in products:
    print(p)

True

crème radiance
crème douceur
absolue precious pure
mousse radiance
crème mousse confort
eau fraîche douceur
tonique confort
tonique pure focus
gel radiance
```

I am using 2.5.3:

```
In [8]: import requests

In [9]: requests.__version__
Out[9]: '2.5.3'
```

You can create a dict of products and prices so your girlfriend can get you to buy her multiple products:

```
products = [x.text.strip().lower() for x in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"product-name"})]
prices = [x.text for x in soup.find_all("span",{"class":"product-sales-price"})]

items = dict(zip(products,prices))
print(items.get("mousse radiance","N/A"))
print(items)

$32.00
{u'cr\xe8me radiance': u'$25.00 - $37.00', u'cr\xe8me douceur': u'$25.00 - $37.00', u'absolue precious pure': u'$58.00', u'mousse radiance': u'$32.00', u'cr\xe8me mousse confort': u'$25.00', u'eau fra\xeeche douceur': u'$38.00 - $51.00', u'tonique confort': u'$25.00 - $44.00', u'tonique pure focus': u'$25.00', u'gel radiance': u'$25.00'}
```